# Remove partial string from macro added to Outlook ribbon

Tags: vba, outlook

I have templates I'm trying to add to users' PCs and have these templates easily accessible in the ribbon. I've been mostly successful except that the name of each macro is far too long.

It was Project1.ThisOutlookSession.OpenTemplate1. I realized the last portion was the name of the sub for opening that particular template. Then I realized I could change "Project1" to anything, whereby shortening the string.

I was wondering how I could go about changing the ThisOutlookSession portion or even better, remove the "Project1.ThisOutlookSession" portion altogether, leaving us with only whatever we name the sub (which will be the template name). My code:

```
'https://www.slipstick.com/outlook/hyperlink-templates/

Dim template As String

Sub OpenTemplate1()
template =     "...Microsoft\Templates\FollowUpOnOrgSurvey.oft"
MakeItem
End Sub

Sub OpenTemplate2()
template = "...Microsoft\Templates\How Are We Doing.oft"
MakeItem
End Sub

Sub OpenTemplate3()
template =     "...Microsoft\Templates\Option1.oft"
MakeItem
End Sub

Sub OpenTemplate4()
template = "...Microsoft\Templates\Option2.oft"
MakeItem
End Sub

Private Sub MakeItem()
Set newItem = Application.CreateItemFromTemplate(template)
newItem.Display
Set newItem = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

`ThisOutlookSession` is a default module name where your VBA macro resides. If you remove that part from the macro name there is a change the VBA sub will not be found at all.

I'd recommend creating a COM add-in instead of VBA macros. They were designed especially for distributing your Office based solution on multiple machines. VBA macros are not designed for distributing on multiple machines. See [Walkthrough: Creating Your First VSTO Add-In for Outlook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668191.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to get started quickly.

Also you may find the [To distribute Microsoft Outlook VBA code to other users](http://www.outlookcode.com/article.aspx?id=28) article helpful.

Comment: I'll take a look into these options. Appreciate the information and point in the right direction.